# My Facebook Login Script Is Stopped Getting User Email

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

my old facebook login script is not working properly for a while..

i can get every user details(name, location, photo etc), except email adress..

it was working fine about 2 month ago; i dont know 'what did change?'..

**index.php**

```
<a onclick='facebookLogin();'>login</a>
<script>
function facebookLogin()
{
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxx&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/facelogin.php&scope=email,user_location,user_birthday','facebook_popup','width=600,height=400');

}
</script>
```

**facelogin.php**

```
    if((!empty($_GET['code']))) {
$code = $_GET['code'];
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=" . urlencode('http://www.example.com/facelogin.php')
           . "&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=" . $code;
$ch=curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

$user_profile = get_user_data($params['access_token']);
```

user_get_data function:

```
function get_user_data($access_token = null)
{
    $url =  'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$access_token;
    // Initialize session and set URL.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Get the response and close the channel.
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $user = json_decode($response);
}
```

At here, for example i can get: $user_profile->name

**but i cant get $user_profile->email.**

Dou you have any idea why?

Comment: Show us what your `get_user_data` function does.

Comment: i added to the below of the question @CBroe

Comment: Make a debug output using `var_dump($user_profile);`, and see what that gets you.

Comment: could you describe, where should i add this? and should i say ECHO?

Comment: After the line where you assign the function return value to that variable. And no, no echo needed, var_dump itself makes the output.

Comment: its too long to write as a commet; but it returns everythnig without email adress (birthday, website, gender, locale, work, position etc)

Comment: Then debug your access token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, and see if it actually includes `email` permission.

Comment: i see email section with OK(Approved) in LOGIN PERMISSIONS at my app's page in facebook. but, dont know how to debug access token? :S

Comment: Output it in your script, and copy&paste it into the debug tool.

Comment: yes.. scope contains email :S it returns: user_birthday, user_religion_politics, user_relationships, user_relationship_details, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, user_education_history, user_work_history, user_website, user_groups, user_managed_groups, user_events, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, user_about_me, user_status, email, publish_actions, public_profile

Comment: And is your email address (I’m assuming you are using your own account to test this?) confirmed with Facebook?

Comment: of course; im using it for years... (and it was working properly about two month ago; dont know what did change)

Comment: OK, one last try – call `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token={your access token here}` in your browser – do you get the email address with now?

Comment: it returns only ID detail :(

Comment: Check your privacy settings for your email, who can see it (in some cases that can make it “invisible” via API as well). And maybe try removing the app from your user account settings completely, and then login again – and see if that changes anything.

Comment: ok.. i understand.. thank you so much CBroe.. but my member database says, the problem is not only for me.. because about a month ago, %90 of members register with facebook(for years); but now its about 20%.. i dont know, maybe its a bug on facebook.. i wrote to facebook now.. thank you again..

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically request permissions to access the user's email

Facebook only gives you access in your `$user_profile` object to things about the user that you have permission to access. Name is there by default (you can't do much for a user without their name), and you get a unique ID for the user for your app, but the email you have to get by asking for special permission when they first log in.

Check the Facebook PHP documentation about that.

Comment: my script was asking permissions about a month ago.. everything was ok.. (?)

Comment: He seems to be posting the email scope along in the js request

Comment: In your code can you get their birthday and location too? Cause you seem to ask for those along with email in the js request.

Comment: yes.. i can get birthate, location, photo etc.. only email returns empty :S